# Theorem about constant complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

**Theorem:** Let $f$ be analytical on $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ and let $|f(z)|=k$ be a constant in $\Omega$. Then it follows that $f$ is constant.

**Question:** My book now says "it's clear that the theorem is wrong if $f$ is a complex function of real variables... But that kind of confuses me. Let's pick $f(z)=1$. Then $f$ is analytical on $\mathbb C$, especially on $\Omega$. Also we have $|f(z)|=1,\quad \forall z \in \Omega$ but $f$ is a complex function of a real variable, and apparently, that shouldn't work.

Can maybe elaborate someone what exactly is meant with that theorem?

Comment: The text means $f\colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb C$. E.G. $f(x) = \exp(\mathrm i 2\pi x), x \in \mathbb R$. Then $f(x) = \cos(2\pi x) + \mathrm i \sin(2\pi x)$ and $\cos, \sin$ are real analytic. But $|f|=1$ while $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: For this theorem, try C-R equations.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)=1$ for $z \in \Omega$, then $f$ is a complex function of a complex variable !

Look at $g(t)=e^{it}$ for real $t$. $g$ is differentiable on $ \mathbb R$, we have $|g(t)|=1$ for all $t$, but $g$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your book just means that there are *some* complex functions of real variables for which the Theorem does not hold - it does not mean that the Theorem fails to hold for *all* such functions.

One example for which the Theorem fails to hold is

$f(x) = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$

for which $|f(x)|=1 \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, but clearly $f$ is not a constant function.

Comment: So f is not analytical?

Comment: Not that. $f$ is real analytic, and the norm $|f|$ is constant, but itself is not a constant function. This explains why "the theorem is wrong if $f$ is a complex function of real variables".